# "Totals" Query: show last non-blank string

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a totals query (one where I clicked the totals button, and it has "group by" columns) in Access 2007. Most of the columns are fine... group by columns, max columns, min columns, etc. For some of them though, I want to extract only the last non-blank (not "" or null) value of a string column.

Here's a sample of what my SQL looks like:

```
SELECT  Min(Duplicates.AttendedODBefore) AS AttendedODBefore,
        Min(Duplicates.ContactByPost) As ContactByPost,
        Last(Duplicates.PlannedStart) As PlannedStart,
        Min(Duplicates.AccessibilityRequirements) AS AccessibilityRequirements,
        Last(Duplicates.UcasNumber) As UcasNumber
--      ^^^^
FROM    DuplicateStudents As Duplicates
GROUP BY
        Duplicates.ID
```

The expression highlighted is the one I want changing to the last non-blank field. Is there an Access-specific or plain SQL expression which will do this?

**Edit:** Turns out that `Min()` and `Max()` work on string values and ignores null values, taking the first and last values alphabetically. It's not perfect, because it doesn't guarantee that the value selected is the last one, but it's better than just a load of nulls which is what using `Last()` might give.

Comment: What does last really mean? It implies an ordering - something that a table doesn't guarantee. So, by "last" you explicitly need to specify an ordering of some column(s) in your table. Say, for example, the column upon which you wish to order is called "entrytime", you could then `select max(entrytime) from DupStu where UcasNumber is not null` to figure out the "key" for the last entry - of course if two records share the same "key" this doesn't work...

Comment: @John Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure how to order the records for a `group by`, but it doesn't seem to matter because they're ordered by the auto-incrementing primary key by default, which puts them in order of when they were created. So that's a side issue really.

Comment: My comment was just the first step - basically if you can define a unique key for your last ordering then you can use this in a subquery that your `group by` will select from. Unfortunately I don't know Access's SQL dialect / capabilities in this regard.

Comment: I see, so you're saying it should order based on whether it is blank or not, then select `last()`? I'll have a play and see what I can come up with. I don't think that's a perfect solution because there's more than one field I'd like to do this with, but it's a possibility if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Access seems resistant to the idea of returning the last non-null value in a query using GROUP BY. Even if your FROM clause were modified to be something like

```
FROM    (
    SELECT allfieldsyouneed 
    FROM DuplicateStudents 
    ORDER BY PlannedStart
) AS SortedDuplicates
```

and the rest of your query were modified to use SortedDuplicates instead, Access doesn't seem to return the last value based on the order you specify. I tested on a table with exactly one blank row and specific orders that I could verify (both an auto-increment field and a value that I checked by using Min and Max), and Access chose to return some other value as Last.

Comment: Right -- First/Last are not affected by ORDER BY at all (I thought they were and only recently discovered that they aren't). I don't use First/Last at all, precisely because I find them unpredictable and can't really think of valid uses for them (when exactly do I find myself wanting to present de facto random data?).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment it seems like your definition of "Last" is:  *the most recently added record, based on an auto-incrementing ID*.  As such, some form of the following should work (it uses a subquery to return the most recent non-null `UcasNumber`):

```
SELECT  Min(Duplicates.AttendedODBefore) AS AttendedODBefore,
        Min(Duplicates.ContactByPost) As ContactByPost,
        Last(Duplicates.PlannedStart) As PlannedStart,
        Min(Duplicates.AccessibilityRequirements) AS AccessibilityRequirements,
        (SELECT TOP 1 D.UcasNumber FROM Duplicates AS D
         WHERE D.UcasNumber Is Not Null
         ORDER BY D.ID DESC) As UcasNumber
FROM    DuplicateStudents As Duplicates
```